# Access parent cell from detailed view swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am having two views: TableViewController with my customs cells and ViewController with detailed information. If user presses one of cells - there is segue to detailed view.

Is there any way to access properties of my custom cell in detailed view?

Comment: Pass which properties you want to access into the detail view.

Comment: for example image of cell that was pressed

Comment: I wasn't asking which properties. I was saying, pass the properties into the detail view or pass a pointer to the cell and then you can access them all. Or even better, simply pass in that cells data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the storyboard, click on the segue and give the segue a name from the attributes inspector.

Then create a `prepareForSegue` override function. If the `segue.identifier` matches the name that you gave your segue, then you can access the cell through the `sender` attribute. Let's assume your named your segue `mySegueName` and you custom cell class is called `MyCustomCell`, then the code would be:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "mySegueName") {
        let myCell = sender as MyCustomCell
        // You can now access any property that is on your custom cell
        // like myCell.customImageView
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you! it helped me
i added new property of MyCustomCell type to my detailed view class and i am passing myCell to it. 
maybe there is a better way?